# Inequality with indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

I want to prove the following inequality:
$$X_1 \  1_{\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda)X_2>0} \leq \ X_1 \ 1_{ X_1>0}$$
 where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables and $\lambda \in [0,1]$.
It is clear from intuition but not able write a formal proof.
Please help me how to proceed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine that if $X_1\leq 0$ the result holds.

If $X_1>0$, examine the feasibility of the joint event $\{X_1>0, \lambda X_1 +(1-\lambda)X_2\leq 0\}$

Comment: Thank you. Using different cases it is now possible to proof.